# Alternative history’s butterfly moments reach lift-off

Tags: meaning

*What if? Alternative history’s butterfly moments reach lift-off.*

This is the title of the [article](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/feb/10/alternative-history-butterfly-moments-reach-take-off-amazon-man-in-high-castle) from the today electronic version of the Guardian. I struggle with the phrase "reach lift-off". Could you please rewrite it for me to understand it.

Comment: "take wing" might have been more appropriate when using the butterfly simile.

Comment: @oerkelens You mean _metaphor_.

Comment: Metaphor?  Maybe "butterfly _allusion_ "

Answer (score 2):

> Alternative history's butterfly moments, after a long period of effort and preparation and failed attempts, are now beginning to succeed (in the marketplace for fiction).

"Lift-off" is the moment in the flight of a rocket when, after the countdown, the rocket's engines fire and the rocket truly begins to fly through the air as intended.

If I understand the headline correctly, though, it's very poor writing. The body of the article explains that butterfly moments are small, hypothetical changes from real history, which lead to enormous consequences (which is wrong; see below). The article isn't really saying that those moments are finally achieving some success, even though that's what the headline means. The body of the article says that the *genre of fiction* that includes these "butterfly moments" is starting to have some success.

---

The article says:

> A “butterfly moment” (named for the so-called butterfly effect) is the point at which our real-world timeline diverges from the alternative-history (AH) timeline. Structuralist historians tend to discount such moments, but if Franz Ferdinand’s driver had gone straight on instead of turning right the history of the 20th century would have been different.

This is pretentious writing. First, it defines "butterfly moment" as a moment when a hypothetical history diverges from real history. Then it brings up "structuralist historians" to suggest that they doubt that history is shaped by crucial events like assassinations—a very different idea from the previous sentence. Also, the claim about structuralist historians is wrong. Structuralism is the theory that the elements of language or culture must be understood in relation to broader mental "structures". It doesn't deny that Archduke Ferdinand's assassination had a great effect on history; the idea is that you can only understand its effect by seeing how it related to broader mental structures like "us vs. them" or "royalty and common people". Finally, the [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) is not that small divergences from certain very special small events have huge consequences, it's that nearly *every* tiny divergence, even whether a butterfly flaps its wings or not, eventually accumulates huge consequences that for all practical purposes are unpredictable—almost the opposite of the idea of alternative history that the article is about.

What's happening here is a common phenomenon in English: the author is throwing big words around with little regard for their meaning, in order to sound more learnèd or profound than he really is.

Answer (score 0):

When a rocket is launched, this is called "lift off". So for something to "reach lift off" is to get to the point that it is starting on its journey.